# Custom View with UILabel in it appears black

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have created a custom UIView that has some set of UILabels in it. I add those UILabels inside the custom view inside its drawRect method.

But the whole custom view appears black on the screen. I have not set any background color for the custom UIView. How Do I fix this?

I tried setting background color to ClearColor but it still looks black.

I tried setting opaque property of the custom view to false and the view obviously disappeared.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Did you set the UILabel's background color to black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't do that in drawRect: method which is intended to draw in the graphic context. If you want to add some specific subviews do it in an init / initWithFrame method.
For me the best way is to create a custom uiviewcontroller subclass and initialize it using a xib (nib) file. Working at controller level is a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,320,35)];
newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *mytext = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 28.0)];
mytext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
mytext.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
mytext.editable = NO;
mytext.text = @"Your label";
[newView addSubview:mytext];
[mytext release];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
[newView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone stumbles upon this thread like I did in 2021. Check to see if you have accidentally toggled 'dark mode'. It will show similar visual 'issues' to the question above.